# What is the diameter of the Cayley graph of $S_n$ w.r.t the generator $\{(12),(23),...,(n−1n)\}$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Given a symmetric group $S_n $ and the generator set : $S = \{(12),(23), . . . ,(n − 1 n) \}$ is there any closed form expression for the diameter of the Cayley graph generated by this set of generator ? Is there any upper bound on that diameter ?

For the given generator set: $diameter(S_2) = 1$, $diameter(S_3) = 3$, $diameter(S_4) = 6$ so does the following hold ?

$diameter(S_n) = nC_2$ [w.r.t the given generator set]

It will be great to have the tightest bound on the diameter w.r.t the given generator set.

Comment: This is answered on  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49365

Comment: The diameter here is $\binom{n}{2}$ as given at the above link. In general, one has an upper bound which is exponential in $\sqrt{n\log n}$. However, a polynomial bound is conjectured, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjABahUKEwjGqZ2vmajGAhVlvHIKHeDCAA0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.uchicago.edu%2F~laci%2Fpapers%2F04soda.diam.pdf&ei=qpCKVcasBeX4ygPghYNo&usg=AFQjCNHDNXmac-VcFVD05LFv3z-RTFhdig&bvm=bv.96339352,d.bGQ).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think for general case there is tighter bound presented at Theorem 1.5 [in this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1596.pdf)

Comment: @aroyc The paper even proves the polynomial bound for sets of generators containing a permutation fixing at least 37% of the points.